# Verifying signature of Amazon Cognito JWT in Erlang fails

Tags: jwt, erlang, amazon-cognito

I've got a web service fronted by Cognito, and I need to verify the signature on the JWT provided in the `x-amzn-oidc-data` header.

My code looks like this:

```erlang
% Req is from cowboy
#{headers := #{<<"x-amzn-oidc-data">> := JWT}} = Req,

[H, P, S] = binary:split(JWT, <<".">>, [global]),
Header = jsx:decode(base64url:decode(H)),
_Payload = jsx:decode(base64url:decode(P)),
Signature = base64url:decode(S),

% Assert that it's ES256-protected and get the Key ID.
#{<<"typ">> := <<"JWT">>, <<"alg">> := <<"ES256">>, <<"kid">> := Kid} = Header,

% TODO: Get the region from IMDS.
Region = <<"eu-west-1">>,

% Get the signing public key.
KeyUrl = [<<"https://public-keys.auth.elb.">>, Region, <<".amazonaws.com/">>, Kid],
{ok, 200, _Headers, KeyPem} = hackney:get(KeyUrl, [], <<>>, [with_body]),

?LOG_INFO("Key PEM = ~p", [KeyPem]),

[KeyInfo] = public_key:pem_decode(KeyPem),
Key = public_key:pem_entry_decode(KeyInfo),

Msg = iolist_to_binary([H, <<".">>, P]),
Verified = public_key:verify(Msg, sha256, Signature, Key),

?LOG_INFO("Verified = ~p", [Verified]),
```

But `Verified` is always `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried both `jose` and `jwerl`. They also fail. `jose` fails because it attempts to re-encode the JWT, and since the original is non-canonical, the signature doesn't match. `jwerl` fails for an unknown reason.

Comment: Have you tried logging `Key`?  Is it one of the types allowed in `public_key:verify/4` for the 4th arg?

Comment: @7stud It looks like a valid EC public key. If I do something similar -- https://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2023/12/08/elliptic-curve-signing-erlang/ -- where I generate the key, it works fine.